# Meaning of "futurum instans"

Tags: latin

I am writing a book, quoting from Aune: “There are several instances in Revelation of this use of ἔρχεται as futurum instans ....” Note that Aune uses the term “futurum instans” for Greek, not Semitic languages. Google Translate tells the term as “be instant” and tells “futurum” as “the future” and “istans” as “instant”.  http://tbt.sagepub.com/content/66/2/129.abstract tells the term as “the imminent future, ‘about to’”. Perseus tells “present, immediate” for “istans” (nothing for “futurum”). If I want to give a brief definition of the term "futurum istans" to the readers of my book, could I give “the imminent future, ‘about to’”?

Comment: Please pretend like you actually tried to find the answer yourself.

Comment: Have you tried Google Translate? It's pretty good and got this one right.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! 1) Why was Google Translate not good enough? 2) This belongs on [Latin.SE] Stack Exchange not this site.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey 1) Because Google translate gives you "be instant", which is not what the term means. 2) This doesn't belong on latin.se.com because it's a term of art in Biblical philology as discussed in *English*.

Comment: I have edited my original words in the aforementioned.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, it's Latin. *Instans* is the present participle of *insto,instare*, which means approaching or impending when used with events. We get the word *instanter*, which means immediately, from the same word. *Futurum* means exactly what you think it does, namely the future. A little time spent with the google reveals that the term applies to verb forms in some semitic languages like Hebrew and Aramaic, in which the present tense is used to describe events about to happen in the near future. We have a parallel in English with a construct like

> It **is going** to rain.

The verb is in the present tense but the sense is that it is about to rain.